# Decode Special character "ì"

Tags: html, json, html-escape-characters

I have a file json with a particular character (ie. ì);

I have my service :

```
   $http({
        url: jsonUrl,                   
        method: "GET"
        }).success(function (data) { // data is an array that contains a list of elements (firstname,lastname,email)
            .....
```

The character ì arrives in the this form � !!!

What I can do??
Thanks

Comment: Your server does not correctly declare the character-set of the JSON response. There is not a lot you can do on the client, you must fix the server side.

Comment: I put this <meta charset="utf-8"> but it is the same!!!

Comment: The error is in the JSON headers. Your website encoding is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP you can set the headers like this (obviously just choose one, preferably the encoding type of the data itself):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

For other languages it's the same string that needs to be passed to the headers, however that will be accomplished.